# odd and even lines different divs count?

Tags: html, css

I have a fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/x18qLnfx/
How to make 3 divs of the same width on odd lines and 4 divs on even lines with `nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even)`?

Comment: If you always have the same number of divs in a row (3 for odd lines and 4 for even ones), it's easier to wrap each row in a container.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: I don't understand your question, what are you trying to create exactly? What line, how the width of the divs has anything to do with it?

Comment: I know how to wrap each row, but I need to do this with odd and even.
Alon, forget about width. Let's suppose, I have 10 lines. I need to make 3 divs on lines 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 lines and 4 divs on lines 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1:

this will do the trick, on every 7n div (7,14,21...) add a margin-right as 25% to take the whole space so only 3 div this row:

```
.wrapper>div:nth-child(7n) {
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

```css
.wrapper>div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper>div {
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(7n) {
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis icing elit. Saepe laboriosam nisi deserunt nesciunt culpa maxime aliquid perspiciatis, officiis! Veritatis temporibus minus reprehenderit consectetur sunt, omnis totam laboriosam mollitia? Eos, repellendus.</div>
</div>
```

### Solution 2 (equal width):

`.wrapper>div:nth-child(7n + 7)` with `width: calc(100% / 3)` you have control over different row, for every 7 div you group them, for the 5th 6th 7th in the group you make the width to `100% / 3` the rest are 25% so have the following effect:

```css
.wrapper>div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper>div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper>div:nth-child(7n + 5),
.wrapper>div:nth-child(7n + 6),
.wrapper>div:nth-child(7n + 7) {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the same html markup and the parent of those divs is called `.blocks-container`, you can do it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/x18qLnfx/3/).

'odd' and 'even' have no meaning since you don't have a container for rows, so your 'periodic' style is applied after 7 children and not two. I hope you use some kind of styles preprocessor, to avoid those long styles declarations.

The font-size: 0 is there to just take care of the markup spaces problem with inline blocks.

Also, if you want to keep your padding of 5px, I would add a second element inside the div and add the padding to that element, if you can't do that, you will have to calculate the width of the element on the fly, so if your divs have `padding: 5px`, their width must be `width: calc(25% - 10px)` and `width: calc(33.33% - 10px)` respectively.

```
.blocks-container div{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
}

.blocks-container {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.blocks-container div:nth-child(7n+1), .blocks-container div:nth-child(7n+2), .blocks-container div:nth-child(7n+3), .blocks-container div:nth-child(7n+4) {
  width: 25%;
  background: green;
}

.blocks-container div:nth-child(7n+5), .blocks-container div:nth-child(7n+6), .blocks-container div:nth-child(7n+7) {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: blue;
}
```